# How to merge a PR w/conflicts in GitHub, **without** merging base into head (the other way) first?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

in one of the repositories I work with some other folks on, we use pull requests as a way to manage our merges and sometimes we get merge conflicts (as normally happens).  Here's the rub: **other developers have been using the GitHub web interface to do the actual merges (in addition to just creating the PRs).**

According to GitHub documentation:

> **Warning:** When you resolve a merge conflict on GitHub Enterprise
> Server, the entire [base
> branch](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/github/getting-started-with-github/github-glossary#base-branch)
> of your pull request is merged into the [head
> branch](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/github/getting-started-with-github/github-glossary#head-branch). Make
> sure you really want to commit to this branch. If the head branch is
> the default branch of your repository, you'll be given the option of
> creating a new branch to serve as the head branch for your pull
> request. If the head branch is protected you won't be able to merge
> your conflict resolution into it, so you'll be prompted to create a
> new head branch. For more information, see "[About protected
> branches](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.22/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches)."

Sometimes this is not actually what we want.  Here's why.

For example, let's say we're working on two feature branches:

```
feature/123
feature/456
```

And `feature/123` is in `staging` but not ready for `master`.

And we want to merge `feature/456` into `staging`, so we create a PR, and it has merge conflicts.

If someone uses the GitHub web interface to merge that PR, what actually happens is as follows:

- GitHub will merge `staging`, which already contains work from `feature/123`, into `feature/456`.
- The user will resolve the conflict.
- GitHub will merge `feature/456` into `staging`.

Unfortunately, once `feature/456` is ready for `master`, when someone performs that merge, the code changes in `feature/123`, which are still not yet ready for prime time, will come along with it into `master`.

I'm 99% certain the idea behind this behavior is that GitHub wants you to resolve the merge conflicts **in the head branch instead of the base branch**, i.e., `feature/456` instead of `staging`.

Is there a way to have GitHub resolve the conflicts in `staging` instead?

Comment: P.S. (of course I already know how to use the command line to merge, I want to see if GitHub can do the merge properly, i.e., one way)

Comment: I'm not sure about GitHub, but I would stop resolving conflicts in the GitHub UI. Resolve them locally, push your festure branch and then submit the pull request to merge the feature branch into staging.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want to do isn't possible, since the documentation says that it works differently than you want.  If you want a different behavior, I think the command line is going to be your option.

Comment: @DarrenEmbry how to do it in command line? I'm in a very similar situation and right now put a PR on hold until I figure this out. Can you please share any resources about how to do it on command line. I think it is not possible in github GUI.